# Need to change location of text on a single Wordpress page only

Tags: css, wordpress

I am pretty new to coding. I'm trying my best to learn as I go but I am completely stuck on one thing that is probably somewhat basic.  I've started a website to share tech resources with educators - thetechtrunk.com.  I played around with the location of the sub header text so that is to the right of my header on the About, Resources page, etc.  However, now on my home page, the text is too far to the right and I'd like to move it further to the left.  I can't for the life of me determine how to move over the "Blog" text on the home page only and not change the location of that on any other page.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to add this rule to your css file -

```
.home .page-title h2 {
    left:0;
}
```